# SQL injection prevention by replacing ' with ''

Tags: web-application, sql-injection, .net

I'm working on a web application which is vulnerable to SQL injection in its search box. It uses ASP.Net (C#) and Microsoft SQL Server.

In the search box it queries like:

```
Select Column1 from TBL where Column2 = N'  Here The Search box Content  ';
```

As you can see the above code is completely vulnerable to SQLi.
What I did to mitigate this was just creating a method to replace all `'` with `''` which in SQL Server means it is a single quotation.

So if a user enters something like  `' order by --` in the textbox the replace function will replace it with `Replace("'","''");` and the SQL Server would never run the attacker's injected SQL.

So I just want to know that am I completely safe against SQLi? Or is there a way to bypass my injection protection?

Comment: You should just use prepared statements instead.

Comment: @Anders What do you mean by a prepared statement ? Regex ?!

Comment: No, not regex. Google it. Or read more about preventing SQLi in different languages [here](http://bobby-tables.com/about.html). (By the way, you do not specify what language the replace function is written in.)

Comment: @Anders I update my question , I use c#. well is it important what language I use ?! I think replace exist in all languages. Are they diffrent ?!

Comment: related: [How to defeat doubling up apostrophes to create SQLi attack?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108472/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not safe at all.

Replacing single-quotes with double-quotes or vice versa will only keep you safe from one type of injection. Also, what if the end user has a legitimate need to enter a single-quote mark?

As was pointed out in the comments, you should use [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Below is an example, taken from the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, the technique is not unique to Microsoft. Every serious database supports prepared statements.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, connection);

// Create and prepare an SQL statement.
command.CommandText =
    "INSERT INTO Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) " +
    "VALUES (@id, @desc)";
SqlParameter idParam = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 0);
SqlParameter descParam = 
        new SqlParameter("@desc", SqlDbType.Text, 100);
idParam.Value = 20;
descParam.Value = "First Region";
command.Parameters.Add(idParam);
command.Parameters.Add(descParam);

// Call Prepare after setting the Commandtext and Parameters.
command.Prepare();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Can you provide an example in which is not safe? I am not a security expert but can't find any. Also consider double quote is the way to escape single quote in string, so for string handling data are not lost. I ask this not because I advocate for this escaping technique but because some legacy code I work with use that mechanism and if broken I would like to know.